# My flutter app moves to a new page even when firebase auth has errors

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app navigates to a new page even when there is error in the function.

i have a signIn button which handles the firebase signIn after which I want the app to move to the next screen after sign in but the button moves to the next screen even when firebase auth has errors.

My question is; How will i move to the next page only when the login is successful

here is my button press function

```
            press: () async {
              if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                formKey.currentState.save();
              }
              await context.read<Authentication>().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: emailController.text,
              password: passwordController.text);
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
              HomeScreen()));
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I see what you are doing wrong you should add a .then() callback after the sign in with email and password you can follow the docs
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#emailpassword-registration--sign-in

Answer (score 1):

your code does not validate if the signin was successful or not,

```
      press: () async {
        if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          formKey.currentState.save();
        }
        context.read<Authentication>().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text).then((user) => {
       //  check if signin is valid or not
         if(user){
               Navigator.pushReplacement(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
         },

        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks you cedar. Please how can i check if signin is valid or not?

Comment: Generally speaking, signInWithEmailAndPassword returns UserCredential object. have a look at UserCredential class, to determine how to check for that.
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html

Answer (score 1):

```
press: () async {
  if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    formKey.currentState.save();
  }
  final FirebaseUser user = await context.read<Authentication>().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text,
      password: passwordController.text);

  if(user != null){

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                HomeScreen()));
  }else{
  //show some dialog - not a user or invalid password etc. for error handling.
  }
},
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem, The button isnt moving to the next screen after signin